# Vowel length of the first "i" of "VIRIDIS"

Tags: vowel-quantity

Could anyone tell me if the first "i" of "VIRIDIS" (green), the one between "v" and "r", is long or short?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viridis

Answer (score 5):

It is short. A good dictionary should indicate this, either with a breve (ĭ) or by marking all long vowels with macrons.

We know this both through poetry (Aeneid V.110: *in mediō, sacrī tripodēs **viridēs**que corōnae*) and through its Romance descendants. In most contexts, short *ĭ* becomes *e* in Romance, while long *ī* becomes *i*. So forms like Spanish *v**e**rde* point to a short vowel.